# Got the answer TypeError: __call__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'max_length' when automatically generating meta descriptions using BERT

Tags: python, google-colaboratory, bert-language-model

I am trying to automatically generate meta descriptions by using Python and BERT on a Google colab sheet, according to this tutorial https://lazarinastoy.com/automatically-generate-meta-descriptions-using-python-bert/#running-bert-using-python.
Everything is working fine until I get to the final module.

```
 # BERT
model = Summarizers()
result = model(body, max_length=160)
full = ''.join(result)
print(full)

  # Storing all values into the list 
metadesc.append(full)

  #save stored values in a in a column
df['Meta Desc'] = metadesc

  #save output
output = df.to_csv('output.csv')
```

This is when I get an error:

```
    The tokenizer class you load from this checkpoint is not the same type as the class this function is called from. It may result in unexpected tokenization. 
The tokenizer class you load from this checkpoint is 'BartTokenizer'. 
The class this function is called from is 'PreTrainedTokenizerFast'.
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-18-e5ad83648d1f> in <module>()
      1 # BERT
      2 model = Summarizers()
----> 3 result = model(body, max_length=160)
      4 full = ''.join(result)
      5 print(full)

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/torch/autograd/grad_mode.py in decorate_context(*args, **kwargs)
     25         def decorate_context(*args, **kwargs):
     26             with self.clone():
---> 27                 return func(*args, **kwargs)
     28         return cast(F, decorate_context)
     29 

TypeError: __call__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'max_length'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Change max_length to max_len   or maxlen and it'll probably work.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but this didn't work.